# Make text show background on hover through the background color

Tags: html, css

So here is the link when i am not hovering over it.

[image]

I tried looking up how too make the text transparent so that you can see the background of the image through the text, but couldn't find anything about this. Here is what it looks like when I hover over the link.

[image]

Here is the code for the div I am doing this in.

```css
#learnmore{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}

#learnmore:link{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}

#learnmore:visited{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}

#learnmore:hover{
    background: white;
    color: transparent;
}

#learnmore:active{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="offer">
    <img src="imgs/detroit.jpeg" title="" alt="">

    <h1>Offer Header</h1>

    <p>Here is a little bit of information about our offer.</p>

    <a href="" id="learnmore">Learn More</a>
    <a href="" id="scrolldown"><img src="imgs/down arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Should `#learnmore:hover{
    background: white;
    color: transparent;
}` be `#learnmore:hover{
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}`?  Why would you set the hover background to white if you want to see through it?

Comment: Try this  #learnmore:hover {background: none;color: #fff;}

Comment: @gabe3886 I think the op wants a "carved-out" text effect where the text is transparent and would take on the color of the header background.

Comment: You have alot of redundant code..

Comment: what do you want it to look like???

Comment: you cant make a text see-through and set it'sbackground at the same time. To make it see through do this `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;-webkit-background-clip: text;`

Comment: May be you are looking for this effect ?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416288/1926369

Comment: Yes I am! Lemme try the code out.

Comment: This did the trick. Can you post it in a comment so I can make it the answer?

Comment: Never mind, that would be a duplicate... Happy that it helped :-)

Comment: Thank you very much vals! This is pretty obscure and would have taken me a couple days to find on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how too make the text transparent so that you can see the background of the image through the text,

You can use `mix-blend-mode: hard-light;` . Also you have lot of code redundancy (you have the same rule for `:link`, `:active` etc) which I have refactored by using a `,` and grouping together.

```css
#learnmore,
#learnmore:link,
#learnmore:visited,
#learnmore:active {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size:40px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#learnmore:hover {
  background-color:white;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
  color: purple;
}
body {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="offer">
  <p>Here is a little bit of information about our offer.</p>

  <a href="" id="learnmore">Learn More</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: This works well in Chrome and (for some reason even FF?!), but you end up with solid color text even on :hover in IE

Comment: @ILoveCSS oh .. didn't check on IE though.. thanks for the heads up.. I will see what can be done

Comment: You forgot to add the background color to the link on hover. It does not work when the bg color changes to white.

Comment: If you add background color then that will cover that image right.  Or do you mean the text should be transparent and background to be white ?

Comment: Just to be clear the answer is in the comments of the original post I made and was provided by vals.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins glad your issue is resolved.. however I updated my code so that its useful for future crowd.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this **fake fix** unless you want to deal with cross-browser-support.

Set the text color on `:hover` *to match the color* of the section of the **header 
background** that's underneath it.

```css
body {
  background: #535686;
  font-size: 22px
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
#learnmore,
#learnmore:link,
#learnmore:visited,
#learnmore:active {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}
#learnmore {
  margin: 10px;
}
#learnmore:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #535686
}
```

```html
<div id="offer">
  <img src="imgs/detroit.jpeg" title="" alt="">
  <h1>Offer Header</h1>
  <p>Here is a little bit of information about our offer.</p>
  <a href="" id="learnmore">Learn More</a>
  <a href="" id="scrolldown"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not using a background color. Its going to be an image.

Comment: Same fix still applies, you just need to get the color value for the section of the the background image that's under your button - which is the value I am using above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using opacity?

```
  #learnmore: hover{
      background: white;
      color: black;
      opacity:.5;
   }
```

Comment: You could even switch it up.. background:black; color:white;